# FreeMarker get list of cached templates in TemplateCache

Tags: java, freemarker

I am trying to get a list of templates that are already in the `TemplateCache` (which is private and hidden behind the Configuration).

I am trying to write a small admin UI to the templates and display what is already cached and call `configuration.removeTemplateFromCache(String)` on a specific template and not everything (`clearTemplateCache` will clear too much and cause too much file IO).  My alternative is to keep a parallel list of template names in a Set and use that as a list of keys, but would be nice if `FreeMarker` provided this for consistency.

Also, it there a reason for hiding the `TemplateCache` contents behind Configuration (while allowing removal by key via public method, but not a list of keys).  Seems like an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TemplateCache` is kind of implementation detail (I guess it's public because Java doesn't allow it to be visible for FreeMarker packages only). The better question is why you can't get the `CacheStorage` from the `Configuration`. Anyway, as of your problem, not even FreeMarker knows the list of templates, because the `CacheStorage` interface doesn't provide any method for querying that. However, you can plug your own `CacheStorage` implementation in via `Configuration.setCacheStorage`, that provides such method, and keep the reference to it somewhere outside FreeMarker. Yeah, it's kind of awkward that you can't just get it from `Configuration`... But on the bright side you can monitor the cache activity however you like.

**Update:** FreeMarker 2.3.20 has `Configuration.getCacheStorage()`, so it's not hidden anymore.

Comment: I added a Set<String> to keep track of what I put in and use that to display contents and remove them to refresh the cache.  Seems to be working fine.